# Karma [Jasmine] - how to separate code from test cases

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

Is there a standard way to separate code from tests by using Jasmine?

== functions.js

```
function sample() {
    return true;
}
```

== functions.spec.js

```
describe('functions', function () {

    it('sample', function () {
        expect(sample()).toEqual(true);
    });

});
```

== karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: __dirname + '/../public/',
        frameworks: [
            'jasmine'
        ],
        browsers : ['PhantomJS'],
        client: {
            jasmine: {
                stopOnFailure: true
            }
        },
        files: [
            'js/**/*.spec.js'
        ]
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance!

---

I was trying to use 'browserify' without success:

== karma.config.js

```
browserify: {
        debug: true,
        plugin: ['proxyquireify/plugin'],
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    preprocessors: {
        'js/**/*.spec.js': ['browserify']
    }
```

== functions.spec.js

```
var source = require('./functions.js');
...
expect(source.sample()).toEqual(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small change in the original file helps:

== functions.js

```
this.sample = function() {
    return true;
};
```